# Xcodebuild commandline fails on signing code with certificates

Tags: xcodebuild

The xcodebuild project , I can open the Xcode UI and build the project. It signs the code also well.
The same I was trying to build using the commandline tool xcodebuild.It gives "Code certificate error"
This is needed to have the process automated.

Comment: See this topic for several solutions for your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866761/setting-a-provisioning-profile-from-within-xcodebuild-when-making-iphone-apps

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the `-target name` correctly, this will use your provision profile.