# Xcode 5 continuous integration CodeSign fail

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, continuous-integration

**Hi there.
I'm trying to configure continuous integration for my iOS app with xcode 5 and OS X Server. I added certificates and p12 to system KeyChain, I also copied provisioning profiles to server folder for profiles.
Integration fails and log shows error message**

**Short message:**

> Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

**Full message:**

> CodeSign
>   /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/c60acccd-d128-d128-b0e3-070a65bdd9dc/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MomentSeller/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MomentSeller.app
>       cd /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/c60acccd-d128-d128-b0e3-070a65bdd9dc/source/Moment
>       setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       Using code signing identity "iPhone Distribution: Company Name. (ZX6C5SJYP9)" and provisioning profile "Moment Seller Production"
>   (E6FC8157-98F3-4A28-BFF3-36EFA6334019)
>       codesign --force --sign C2F81E886780437B90630A748111D3340DC8EFC8 --resource-rules=/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/c60acccd-d128-d128-b0e3-070a65bdd9dc/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MomentSeller/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MomentSeller.app/ResourceRules.plist
>   --entitlements /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/c60acccd-d128-d128-b0e3-070a65bdd9dc/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MomentSeller/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Moment.build/Release-iphoneos/MomentSeller.build/MomentSeller.xcent
>   /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/c60acccd-d128-d128-b0e3-070a65bdd9dc/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MomentSeller/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MomentSeller.app
>   /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/c60acccd-d128-d128-b0e3-070a65bdd9dc/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MomentSeller/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MomentSeller.app:
>   User interaction is not allowed. Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with
>   exit code 1
>
> ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:  CodeSign
>   /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/c60acccd-d128-d128-b0e3-070a65bdd9dc/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MomentSeller/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MomentSeller.app
>   (1 failure)

**Any ideas?
Thanks.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've run into this problem myself. This blog helped me out. http://matt.vlasach.com/xcode-bots-hosted-git-repositories-and-automated-testflight-builds/

As posted by Dominik Kroutvar:

> User interaction is not allowed. Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with
>   exit code 1
>
> This error happens when the following setting is not made manually. As
>   described in one of the posts above you have to put the mobileprofile
>   for code signing in the system keychain. The certificate is called
>   iPhone Distribution:. This distribution certificate must have a
>   private key! Open the Settings dialog either by double click on the
>   private key or through the context menu>Get Info. Then go to Access
>   control and put /usr/bin/codesign in the table. This allows the
>   codesign application to sign your built application. After that
>   everything should work without the meaningless codesign error exit
>   code 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me from suicide... I saw this article but was too stupid and missed this section.

Comment: Nobody should commit suicide due to a programming problem! I'm glad you were saved!

Comment: Thanks, @JoshFeldman - likely just saved our team hours of lost time. Wish there was a tribute button in StackOverflow ;)

Comment: In case someone is wondering press 'Cmd' + 'Shift' + '.' with the file dialog open to show hidden files, i.e., the /usr directory. Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/a/23292052/1623530

Answer (score 0):

[As already stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29293214/1285846) you simply need to run `security -v unlock-keychain -p "$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" "$KEYCHAIN"`.

Run this before the build and the codesign succeeds.