# OSX security find-identity can't find identities in ssh-ed machine

Tags: macos, ssh, keychain

I am ssh-ing into `otherosx` OSX (10.10.3) machine from my OSX(10.10.3) machine in order to build a mac application.

```
ssh user@otherosx
```

Then on `otherosx` I try to import identities like this:

```
security default-keychain -s /path/to/my/login.keychain
security unlock-keychain 
security import my_identity.p12 -P passphrase
```

Then I try to find my identity:

```
security find-identity
```

and I get this:

```
Policy: X.509 Basic
  Matching identities
   0 identities found

  Valid identities only
   0 valid identities found
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Did anyone experience the same issue?

PS. I also tried full paths everywhere, and `security list-keychains -s /path/to/my/login.keychain` before unlocking keychain and searching for identities.

Comment: So you're not providing an identity to find when you invoke `security find-identity`?

Comment: @trojanfoe Well, no. When I execute `security find-identity` on local machine it finds all my identities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, it seems that if you import like this:

```
security import my_identity.p12 -k /path/to/my/login.keychain -P passphrase
```

then it works. At least worked once for me.

It seems this might also be related to these questions:

["User interaction is not allowed" trying to sign an OSX app using codesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205162/user-interaction-is-not-allowed-trying-to-sign-an-osx-app-using-codesign)

[Xcode, Codesign Error from Jenkins / SSH - "User Interaction is not allowed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475404/xcode-codesign-error-from-jenkins-ssh-user-interaction-is-not-allowed)

Answer (score 0):

Run the command "security list-keychain" **remotely** and check if it is listing your keychain. I my case it wasn't. So I fixed it upgrading my OSX to the last version. I read about some problems with the Sierra version of the OSX.