# ssh other macbook and `security find-identity -p codesigning -v` no permissions

Tags: macos, ssh, keychain

When I ssh macbook as root user and run

```
security find-identity -p codesigning -v`
```

I get

> 0 valid identities found

But when I run the following **directly** on the macbook

```
security find-identity -p codesigning -v
```

It shows all identities.

I read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914718/osx-security-find-identity-cant-find-identities-in-ssh-ed-machine) but still can't solve it.

how can I show all identities with ssh on macbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that you should [login to the remote machine with a ssh private key](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/logging-in-with-an-ssh-private-key-on-linuxmac/), just like `ssh -i /path/to/your/id_rsa root@remote.com`. Then you can have permission to access all security data.