# Programmatically add provisioning file and certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Is there a way to set up an Xcode project to point to the provisioning file and the certificate file themselves rather than going through keychain and whatever Xcode does with provisioning profiles?

If not, is there a programmatic way to add them to keychain and Xcode so that an Xcode project can be configured to use them? 
(There is a related Q&A mentioning putting the provisioning file in a certain folder that Xcode uses, but that no longer appears to be the case in the latest Xcode.)

Note that I already know how to do all this manually. I need to do it programmatically for a potentially large number of certificates and profiles.

Comment: All you have to do is drag & drop them onto Xcode's icon, the rest is done automatically.

Comment: To add onto @NSPostWhenIdle once you drag and drop you can switch the profile and cert by selecting your project target and changing the value for 'Dev' and 'Release' Code Signing under Build Settings

Comment: Thanks for the replies. However, I need to do this programmatically from a program on a build server - no clicking, no dragging, etc. To put it alternatively, everything from a command line.

Comment: Is it really necessary to this???

Comment: For reasons that I can't go into here, yes it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This stack overflow question may be what you want:

[Setting a provisioning profile from within xcodebuild when making iPhone apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866761/setting-a-provisioning-profile-from-within-xcodebuild-when-making-iphone-apps)

It allows you to specify the provisioning profile to use using xcodebuild, which is what you're using if you're doing this on the command line.