# Xcode bot fails with "no activity for too long" error

Tags: xcode, xcode-bots, xcode-server

My Xcode bot integrations fail with the following error.

> Assertion: Running task was terminated because it produced no activity for too long.

From the bottom of the log:

```
Sampling completed, processing symbols...

Sample analysis of process 4470 written to file /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Integration-ef7a2c98cd2307fc71923f1123ea23f7/4470.sample

sample[5774]: sample cannot find any existing process you have access to which has a name like 'Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool'; try running with `sudo`.

sample[5775]: sample cannot find any existing process you have access to which has a name like 'ibtool'; try running with `sudo`.

sample[5776]: sample cannot find any existing process you have access to which has a name like 'ibtoold'; try running with `sudo`.

** BUILD INTERRUPTED **
```

Interestingly, the integrations worked the day before and started failing today without any known changes to the server configuration. Is there a way to fix those errors and make the integrations run?

OS X 10.11 (15A244d), Xcode 7.0 (7A176x), OS X Server 4.1.56 (15S2186i)

Comment: Restarting the server computer fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to restart the server computer daily otherwise bots get stuck with this error.

Comment: I have this problem too, my error message said "Running task was terminated because it produced no activity for too long."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This did the trick for us when we ran into the same issue today:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22637896/43996

Comment: That is an issue with code signing. Is it really the issue OP is having? My integration fails to complete tests on the bot (they work fine locally), and I get exactly the same messages in the raw log.

Comment: @Henrik FYI, this definitely seems to be related to the OP's problem. Just to provide some more detail.  We had executed the fix linked (allowing all access to keys). It definitely got things working.   Skip ahead a week and it started failing again.  The second fix... repeat the fix again.  We had to get disallow then allow access again to our keys.  Seems non-sensical given where the build hung for us but also seems to be the fix.

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone who attempts to use this fix (which did work for me as well). If you are attempting to perform the steps via vnc/teamviewer etc, it wont work. You have to use a mouse and keyboard directly attached to your build server. Its apparently related to this patch https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205375     right at the bottom the portion for SecurityAgent     `Description: A method existed for applications to create synthetic clicks on keychain prompts. This was addressed by disabling synthetic clicks for keychain access windows.`

Answer (score 0):

Created a new bot with exact configuration and that did the trick for me. [Stackoverflow  xcode-server-ibtool-build-failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907543/xcode-server-ibtool-build-failures)

Answer (score 0):

I created a new simple project to test Xcode Bot and the same problem happened.
I have try several ways including allow all items to access keychain, however, it didn't work until I unchecked the `Code coverage`.