# How to fix Xcode's code sign issues on Jenkins?

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I have done the usual steps of making the `xcodebuild` work on jenkins, which would be installing "keychain & provisioning profiles" plugin, uploading the right keychain+profiles in the plugin's configuration, and using `security -v unlock-keychain`, and `PROVISIONING_PROFILE` in the `xcodebuild` command.

the build goes forward O.K., even runs the defined `postbuild` scripts defined in the Xcode project, and creates the `.app` folder with all the necessary content, but fails here...

```
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/iOS_feature/workspace/build/Applications/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib: User interaction is not allowed.
*** error: Couldn't codesign /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/iOS_feature/workspace/build/Applications/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib: codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Any ideas what could cause this? from what I understand, the Keychain+ProvisioningProfiles are in place since the build doesn't fail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be).

Comment: are you passing the password to `security -v unlock-keychain`? because otherwise it'll do nothing without user interaction. we've seen this a few times, i'll add our solution below and see if it works for you

Comment: sure, i use the two parameters coming from keychain plugin `security -v unlock-keychain -p "${KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD}" "${KEYCHAIN_PATH}"`

Answer (score 2):

firstly, are you passing your keychain password to the `security -v unlock-keychain` command (using `-p`)? it's definitely not an ideal solution, because it probably requires exposing your password in clear text on your build server.

our workaround for this problem is to login to the actual machine (remote screen sharing or locally sitting at the machine). run a single build from the desktop, whether it be command line or in Xcode. (you might be asked to "always allow" but i'm not 100% sure under which scenarios this will happen).

from then on, all your remote CI builds should pass through code signing successfully.

Comment: OK, I will try to run Xcode on the workspace and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

It's not due to reverse DNS failing or self signed certs on the Jenkins box is it?

We had similar issues though not on Jenkins but Xcode 7 does these extra two checks we found.

Answer (score 0):

Does CodeSign have permission to use the private key?

Whenever I see this error, this is usually the solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22637896/78496