# Private key changes in Keychain Access not saved

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing

I have exact the same problem as describe here:
["User interaction is not allowed" trying to sign an OSX app using codesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205162/user-interaction-is-not-allowed-trying-to-sign-an-osx-app-using-codesign)

So now I want to change the private key access control to Allow all applications to access this item. When I check this option everything looks fine; I've been asked to enter the administrator password and after that the windows closes.

But when I check the Access Control of the key again the other option is checked again; only allow list of applications...

Answer (score 5):

Already found a solution:

Remove the cert/key from System.
Add the cert/key to login and change the Access Control (changing here worked...).
Copy the cert/key to System. The access control is as it should be.