# El Capitan + Xcode 7.1 not letting me allow enterprise signing

Tags: ios, xcode7, provisioning-profile

I've got an enterprise cert and in-house provisioning profile wired up. I've got the cert installed, and Xcode 7.1 prompts me with this nice permissions request alert. I click Always Allow. I click Allow.

No matter what I click, it just ignores me and asks again:

[image]

Well, unless I click Deny. But why would I want to do that?!

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205162/user-interaction-is-not-allowed-trying-to-sign-an-osx-app-using-codesign/22637896#22637896), but I can't click *that* Allow button either!

Also: [related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/208704/74519)

Help?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are using any app that helps you enter admin password, like MacID?

Comment: @Behdad nope - out of the box El Cap keychain.

Comment: I came across this issue as well, it turned out that I had to disconnect my Wacom Tablet, and use a regular mouse (Magic Mouse in my case) in order for the 'allow' or 'always allow' buttons to work. Such a weird bug to diagnose.

Comment: And what was equally confusing is that if both my Wacom Tablet and my Magic mouse were connected, clicking either 'allow' button still didn't work. Only removal of the Wacom tablet remedied the issue. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just got this fixed. I use a plugin called [SmoothMouse](http://smoothmouse.com) that improves acceleration of trackpad and mouse. It likely integrates with the accessibility APIs in OS X and thus triggers the same behavior as screensharing. Disabling the plugin resolved the problem.

Comment: That was entertaining. I just updated our (remote) new build server to El Cap and I haven't yet provisioned it. Unless OSX server can handle this for me, looks like I'll be making a trip into the office so I can click "Allow".

Comment: And positively re**rded.

Comment: Lucky they didn't install ElCap on the Mars Rover.

Comment: Is there any solution to use SmoothMouse (or similar software) and not having this stupid problem? I use MagicPrefs and I'd really like to continue using it.

Comment: I'd say just disable the plugin when you need to click allow, then re-enable.

Comment: How exactly did you disable SmoothMouse? I unchecked "Enabled For Mice" from System Preferences, but that didn't help. Unplugged the external mouse and used MacBooks's trackpad, but still not help. This just shows how OS X code quality has deteriorated since Snow Leopard. OS X is today full of problems and it's as unreliable and slow as Windows. And that is a really sad thing.

Comment: I actually had to uninstall the plugin completely IIRC, unless there's an option to disable it entirely in the settings control but I don't think so.

Answer (score 6):

Are you running from a remote machine? Apparently there [was a recent security hole](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/09/sneaky-adware-caught-accessing-users-mac-keychain-without-permission/) where remote agents were gaining access to the keychain by scripted control of the mouse.

So it was 'fixed' by preventing this. After finding a keyboard, mouse, etc and wiring the machine up, I was able to allow keychain access. After this the machine could run remotely again.

**Edit:**

It is also necessary disable Apple remote desktop and ensure there are no active VNC connections to the machine.

Comment: No, I completely disabled screen sharing and remote management in settings. Nothing remote control-wise is going on at all.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was that I was running a remote session using TeamViewer.

When I logged in the actual computer, the 'allow' button pressed successfully.

Comment: I think this is my problem and it's so freaking stupid! My remote computer is in another country, how am I supposed to to log in the actual computer? There has to be a way to go around this, right?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by unplugged all the mouse and keyboard on the Mac, and using the trackpad and buildin keyboard, and that works for me.I guess it is apple's security policy.