# Xcode codesign exit code 1 in Jenkins build

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, jenkins, codesign

My environment is:

```
OSX 10.11 El Capitan
Unity3D 5.3.4f1
Xcode 7.3
Jenkins 1.642.4
```

The `Xcode` project file generated by `Unity3D` build process.

I import Developer & Team certificate to jenkins user's `login.keychain`

```
/Users/Share/Jenkins/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

Also copy all Provisioning Profiles to

```
/Users/Share/Jenkins/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles
```

Build is running fine. And then run

```
/usr/bin/codesign return exit code 1
```

I tried many way to fix this.
But is not work yet.

I logged in as jenkins user.
And try to build xcode project
The codesign is build success.

I have no idea to figure out this problem.
Could anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks

#### Update 1:

```
sudo su - jenkins
```

`xcodebuild` is also failed on `codesign`.

#### Update 2:

Screenshot
Build as `sudo su - jenkins`
[Change user to jenkins to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kQbK.png)

[Logged in as jenkins to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN2oD.png)

Jenkins web console output
Only 2 links allow, so here is the address i.stack.imgur.com/dYFOW.png

#### Update 3:

Maybe the codesign issue could like execute codesign via ssh remote build.
Does any idea to solve this?

#### Update 4:

I tried ssh.
after security unlock keychain.
It's passed.

#### Update 5:

Directly `run /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign ...` pass
But execute `xcodebuild` still failed on codesign...

#### Update 6:

```
security set-keychain-settings -t 3600 -l ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

I added this to build step. It was passed built on jenkins.
So the problem maybe is **TIMEOUT**

God... It's stuck me TWO DAYS...
Thanks everyone.
Have good day

Comment: Are you unlocking the keychain on the command line using `security unlock keychain`?

Comment: Yes, but jenkins always build failed.

Comment: Have you tried logging in as `jenkins` and using Xcode (not `xcodebuild`) to build the generated Xcode project?  The Xcode project generated by Unity will not have the correct developer id/provisioning profiles set unless you have edited it between generation and build (actually that's probably not true about the provisioning profiles as it can get the right one based on the bundle id, which is set correctly by Unity).

Comment: OSX jenkins login and open terminal to run xcodebuild passed. That's what I thought the jenkins should pass. But there is not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**. Got to **Xcode** -> **Preferences** -> **Accounts** -> Choose your account, and then **View Details** -> refresh the Provisioning Profile. If the **refresh** button is **missing** then click on **Download All** button then  **restart** XCode.

EDIT:

After looking at the picture you posted, I noticed an error before the error you posted. It says "“**User interaction is not allowed**". So try the following below.

**2**. KeyChain may be locked:
**Keychain Access** -> **Keychain First Aid** -> **Repair**

OR do it by code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21327591/3785314

**3**. It could be a timeout issue when building. Try

**security set-keychain-settings -t 3600 -l ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain**

**4**. Login your build user via the GUI and open Keychain Access. Select your signing private key, right-click, choose Get Info, change to the Access Control tab and select the "Allow all applications to access this item".
[image]

["User interaction is not allowed" trying to sign an OSX app using codesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205162/user-interaction-is-not-allowed-trying-to-sign-an-osx-app-using-codesign)

Comment: Thanks, but I logged in as jenkins user was built success. So I think is not this problem.

Comment: I don't know what jenkins. Open your project with xcode and do what is in my answer then re-start it and then close it again. It will update the certificate in project. Now try your build command with jenkins again...

Comment: Done. But still failed. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I updated my answer. If that doesn't work then I can't help.

Comment: I already allow all applications to access. Terminal build success. But Jenkins failed. Thanks again.

Comment: You only replied to one answer. Have you tried #2 and #3?