# Xamarin.iOS automated build failing with "User interaction is not allowed." on VSTS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-devops

So I am using **Visual Studio Team Services** to automate my `Xamarin.iOS` application build on my physical Mac machine using the VSTS agent [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent).

I am getting a strange error when it comes to the build step of my `Xamarin.iOS` build definition and it is erroring with:

> /Users/chrisjohn/myagent/_work/1/s/Myapp/Myapp/Myapp.sln
>   (default targets) -> (Build target) ->
>
> /Users/myUser/myagent/_work/1/s/Myapp/Myapp/Myapp.iOS/Myapp.iOS.csproj
>   (default targets) ->
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets
>   (_CodesignAppBundle target) ->
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets:
>   **> error : Tool exited with code: 1. Output:
>   /Users/myUser/myagent/_work/1/s/Myapp/Myapp/Myapp.iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/Myapp.app:
>   User interaction is not allowed.**

where the bit in **Bold** is the real error:

So you can see the error is essentially `User Interaction is not allowed`

I have tried a fix from [this answer: “User interaction is not allowed” trying to sign an OSX app using codesign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22637896/2987066) but it doesnt really say which key I need to grant access to. I tried granting access to my developer keys but it still errors with the same error:

I have also tried moving my developer profile keys to the System keychain but still no such luck

I couldnt find any information on Xamarin talking about this error.

Has anyone seen this error before? Surely this is something that ALL `Xamarin.iOS` developers are encountering?

Comment: Could you make sure that you're using the latest Xamarin tools on the Build server? Also, please post the [full build log](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1675684-where-can-i-find-my-version-information-and-logs-#verbose-build-output-logs)

Comment: @Prashant I am using Xamarin Studio 6.0 (build 5174) and my verbose logs are [here](http://www.filedropper.com/4buildxamariniossolutionfieldstrikefieldstrikemovefieldstrikemovesln) hope that helps

Comment: Does it occur if you copy the code to your build agent and build it manually?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT The error does not occur when manually building my project on my build machine. I copied the code to my build machine and managed to build successfully.

Comment: @user1 When you configure the build agent on the machine, did you configure it to run as service?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Yes the build agent is running as a service

Comment: @user1 Reconfigure it to interactive mode and then try again: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/blob/master/docs/start/configvsts.md

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Running it as interactive mode worked. Is this a bug that needs reporting? What is the bug here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue run your VSTS agent in interactive mode. Info on how to do this found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/blob/master/docs/start/configvsts.md

It is an expected result since that's the difference between Service mode and Interactive mode. Just as the name indicates: Interactive mode allow interaction during the build.