# The code signature version is no longer supported

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

An app signed with a codesign version provided on an older macOS, like Catalina (10.15) will not run on iOS 15 because the lastest version you can install is Xcode 12.4.

Xcode 12.5 seems to change the behavior of codesigning. When installing you get the error message:

> The code signature version is no longer supported

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

### Notice

This answer is mostly for people using older versions of Xcode. My build farm was for a time stuck at Xcode 12.4 because some Mac minis couldn't be upgraded past Catalina. If you are using a recent Xcode 13+ this is not your issue. Probably cruft of some kind in your project.

If you're still using an Xcode 12 release it is time to let go. The only reason to use 12.4 would be because you're stuck on Catalina and new problems are cropping up that will not be worked around so easily.

### codesign --generate-entitlement-der

Apple has changed the codesign signature to include DER encoded entitlements in addition to the plist encoded entitlements. This additional DER encoded entitlements section is required in iOS 15 and becomes the default behavior of codesign in the latest Xcode. To use codesign on an older machines with an older version of Xcode add the `--generate-entitlement-der` flag to your call to codesign.

If signing through Xcode, you can add this flag to the `OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS` setting in the Build Settings tab.

[image]

If codesigning at the command-line:

```
CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=$( xcrun --find codesign_allocate ); export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE
xcrun codesign --generate-entitlement-der ...
```

The source of this information was the [Apple Forum thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682775) and the answer from Matt Eaton in DTS at Apple.

In the [Xcode 12.5 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12_5-release-notes) there is also a reference to the [new signature format](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode/using-the-latest-code-signature-format). However, it seems the information is not entirely correct.

## General advice

If you have a non-trivial setup like CocoaPods, you should probably de-integrate and re-integrate and of course do a project clean. These sorts of 'me too' answers really just add noise to the signal and anyone doing this sort of development should have already tried this.

Comment: This got my application onto the iPhone (iOS 15), but now it says all my cocoapods have invalid signatures. Anyone has a fix for that? .app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' (code signature invalid (errno=1)

Comment: Commenting out  #use_frameworks! in the podfile worked, pods are then compiled in and signed, but that led to other problems in my workspace... Seem's like its time to get a new Macbook with support for the latest OSX and XCode...

Comment: @Bassebus You will need to force resign from the bottom up all 'signables' like frameworks. I avoid signing in Xcode as much as possible and have a python script that directly handles signing because of this kind of nonsense.

Comment: I got it working by adding the `--generate-entitlement-der` flag to each target

Comment: Just to add a little detail to make it easier to find:  Select your app (not project) target, Build Settings, All (not Basic), Signing, Other Code Signing Flags.  Add the specified flag to both Debug and Release.  Xcode 12.4  Fixed my problem!  Note that I already had added the iOS 15.1 device support folder (available here https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport) to my old Xcode installation.  MacOS Catalina 10.15.5

Comment: will an app signed this way continue to work on devices below ios 15?

Comment: Great question, and the answer is yes.

Answer (score 53):

Here are some visual directions to [@CameronLowellPalmer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68467307/4833705).

I got the steps from
@WayneHenderson's comment underneath the accepted answer.

Follow the red arrows steps 1 - 11 (there is no 8, I made a mistake and went from 7 straight to 9).

The **most important** thing is step **4**, make sure to select `All` or you won't find the `Other Code Signing Flags` options.

For step **5** just enter `Other Code Signing Flags` into the search container.

Steps 9 - 11 is where you enter `--generate-entitlement-der`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it fails to be concise. An answer to the question does not need to turn into an Xcode specific tutorial. This is identical to my answer, but with an elaborate Xcode how-to.

Answer (score 33):

- Xcode > Target > General
- Section "Embedded Framework, Libraries and Embedded Content"
- Set all frameworks in the `Embedded` field to "Do not Embed"

Comment: Using packages with Swift Package manager was causing this issue for me (specifically for Firebase).  When I switched to CocoaPods and set the frameworks to "Do Not Embed", it resolved the issue.

Comment: Well that will result in a broken binary. If the framework is not part of the standard iPhone SDK you'll have a non-functional app unless it is embedded.

Answer (score 24):

You will need to add the `--generate-entitlement-der` to your `OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS` under Build Settings.

[image]

Comment: That is stated in my answer.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer This option is not working with embedded targets. Mobile app with watchOS

Comment: Also, any idea how to pass the same of Azure, Xcode task.

Comment: @Amit that is because the project is not correctly setup.

Answer (score 11):

For people who use Xcode13 like me, the problem may not be because of the code signature of our apps (To check the code signature of apps, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/using-the-latest-code-signature-format), but due to the code signature of one of the dependencies, and removing the dependency solves the problem.

In my case, I remove the dependencies one by one, and eventually found that the culprit is `FirebaseAnalyticsOnDeviceConversion`. [remove dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DprZN.jpg)

Comment: This fix worked., didn't have to mess with code signing. I don't use Cocoapods anymore, all SPM based packages. Seems there is a signing issue with `FirebaseAnalyticsOnDeviceConversion`

Comment: You are correct this should NOT apply to Xcode 13. The accepted answer is for people using older versions of Xcode

Comment: I am using 14.2 facing the above error. How can i resolve this

Answer (score 6):

I have spent 2 days to find this issue, Finally i got the solution here from the person Lance Samaria. I would like to share it.

Target-> Build Settings -> Other Code Signing Flags
Add this code --generate-entitlement-der to both Debug and Release

After that Go to Target-> General->Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Contents -> Change to "Do not Embed"

Also I renewed Provisioning Profile and IOS Distribution Certificates.

Now Clean Build Folder and Run Your Project.

Thank you so Much for Lance Samaria

Comment: Please don't add _"thanks"_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](/help/why-vote).

Comment: this step resolves my problem :   “After that Go to Target-> General->Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Contents -> Change to "Do not Embed",  coz this framework is a static framework which should not be embeded  to the final app.

Comment: A static framework or library is 'embedded' in the binary, so to speak. When you link against a static library the objects are pulled from the archive into the main binary. It should however not be copied into the frameworks folder, because that would be useless.

Comment: Target-> General->Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Contents -> Change to `Do not Embed` works for me ... you save my ass thanks alot

Comment: Getting exactly the error described in the question, with Xcode 14.3 and iOS 16.4 on the device, and having things in various states from other attempted solutions, ***THIS*** is what worked.  Not everybody reaching this thread has Xcode 12, so while some answers may work there, this one seems to have applicability beyond older Xcode versions.

Answer (score 5):

After testing all solutions, Only one worked for me. Because XCode adds sign signature automatically when you add Framework, Any Framework that needs to `Embed & Sign` should remove, and add again. Xcode will add the new sign signature automatically.

1. Go to YourTarget>Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Contents.
2. Remove all frameworks that are `Embed & Sign`, except CocoaPods.
3. add removed frameworks again and set to `Embed & Sign`.
4. check that `pods` framework set on `Do Not Embed`

Now clean and run your app on your device.

Answer (score 4):

I want to share my solution. This worked for me using XCode 12.3, macOS Catalina, and tested using Adhoc distribution.

1. Build, archive, export ipa as usual using XCode.
2. Now you have the IPA file, then rename it to zip extension. (make a backup if needed)
3. Extract it. There should be a `Payload` folder.
4. Open terminal, cd to your IPA directory, then run command:

   `codesign -s "CERTIFICATE_NAME" -f --preserve-metadata --generate-entitlement-der ./Payload/YOUR_APP.app`

   - `CERTIFICATE_NAME` is your certificate name located in keychain. It maybe looks like this: `Apple Distribution: XCompany (XXXXXX)`
   - `YOUR_APP` is your .app file name located in `Payload` folder.
5. This warning showed up, I ignored it.

   `Warning: default usage of --preserve-metadata implies "resource-rules" (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)!`
6. Then run zip command:

   `zip -ru myapp_resigned.ipa Payload`
7. Done. You can redistribute the new IPA.

Comment: Certificate name should be something like: iPhone Distribution: <Company> (<TeamID>). Not starting with Apple?

Comment: Anyway, the result doesn't install for me: /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.Jrikte/extracted/Payload/umajin_viewer_test.app : 0xe8008017 (A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted.)

Comment: certificate name depends on how you would distribute your bundle (dev/adhoc/enterprise). in my case its an adhoc so i use `distribution` certificate.

Comment: did you try to re-signing a debug ipa? if so, then you can set `OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS` in xcode as Cameron mentioned.

Comment: Signing is often more complicated than that. First, you need to blow away all codesigning artifacts as a precaution, then sign the 'signables' from the bottom up.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/palmerc/d422ad7ed670b080a604bbc1a3dd7643

Comment: Yeah, I needed to sign an embedded bundle as well as the binary and overall app. Eventually just added the flags to Xcode and it all worked.

Comment: Manually ressign works fine.
Adding --generate-entitlement-der in xcode failed ( xcode 12.4 )

Comment: @Stephane Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68931476/this-code-signature-is-no-longer-supported-when-building-app-on-iphone-12/69381225#69381225

Comment: @Stephane All we use is 12.4

Answer (score 2):

Just my two cents.

As pointed out in other responses, now to sign ios app (compatible with ios and ipados 15) with `codesign` command on MacOS prior to Big Sur add the `--generate-entitlement-der` flag. I can sign my app with Xcode 10.3 using this python 2.7 (tried both on MacOS Mojave 10.14 and MacOS Catalina 10.15) snippet code:

```py
from fabric.api import local

local('cp %s "%s"' % ("/path/to/embedded.mobileprovision", app_full_path))
local('xattr -rc %s' % app_full_path)
local("codesign -f --generate-entitlement-der -vv -s \"%s\" --entitlements \"%s/Entitlements.plist\" %s" % (
    env.code_sign_identity, app_full_path, app_full_path)
)
```

Output example log:

```
[localhost] local: cp /path/to/embedded.mobileprovision "/path/to/Payload/appname.app"
[localhost] local: xattr -rc /path/to/Payload/appname.app
[localhost] local: codesign -f --generate-entitlement-der -vv -s "iPhone Distribution: COMPANYNAME S.p.A." --entitlements "/path/to/Payload/appname.app/Entitlements.plist" /path/to/Payload/appname.app
/path/to/Payload/appname.app: replacing existing signature
/path/to/Payload/appname.app: signed app bundle with Mach-O universal (armv7 arm64) [com.name.reverse.dns]
```

Some additional tips...

- MacOS keychain should contains the Apple certificate used to create the mobile provisioning profile, which is also utilized to distribute the app we’re signing. You can check it using the command `security find-identity -p codesigning`:

  ```bash
    $ security find-identity -p codesigning

    Policy: Code Signing
        Matching identities
        1) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA "iPhone Distribution: COMPANYNAME S.p.A."
        ...
        13) CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC "iPhone Developer: Name Surname (DDDDDDDDDD)"
        13 identities found

        Valid identities only
        1) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA "iPhone Distribution: COMPANYNAME S.p.A."
        ...
        13) CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC "iPhone Developer: Name Surname (DDDDDDDDDD)"
        13 identities found
  ```
- After the `ipa` zip archive creation, you can use the Gem `ipa_analyzer` (https://github.com/bitrise-io/ipa_analyzer) to verify if the app is correctly signed:

  ```bash
  $ zip -9 -y -r /path/to/appname.ipa /path/to/Payload
  $ gem install ipa_analyzer --user-install
  $ PATHAPP="/path/to/appname.ipa"
  $ ~/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin/ipa_analyzer -i ${PATHAPP} -p --info-plist --prov | grep -E "ExpirationDate|CFBundleIdentifier|DER-Encoded-Profile"
    "DER-Encoded-Profile": "#<StringIO:0x00000f0000000008>",
    "ExpirationDate": "2022-09-18T12:15:25+00:00",
    "CFBundleIdentifier": "com.name.reverse.dns",
     ...
  ```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/trincadev/de6e9383fe68f58711637784acb757d4) a complete output example.
As additional references about this issue, you can read also this [Apple documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/using-the-latest-code-signature-format) and this [Apple forum post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682775#681438022).

---

EDIT: this procedure it's working also with MacOS Monterey (version 12.6.1) and Xcode Version 14.1 (14B47b).

Answer (score 2):

The following changes solved my problem

- Go to `Project Target` and select `General`
- Scroll down to `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`
- Turn any `Embed & Sign` to `Do Not Embed`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will help somebody one day, but the solution for me was connected with the pods and their framework.
When I switched settings to **Do not embed** everything worked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What helped in my case was `pod deintegrate` and `pod install`. That's all.

I had this problem with the newest Xcode version (13.4.1). As the installation on an iOS device actually stoped working out of nowhere (it did install successfully 10 min ago before I downgraded one dependency), I doubted the proposed solutions relate to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For those who still fails after adding `--generate-entitlement-der` to `OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS` like @Cameron Lowell Palmer's anwser, try add `-o runtime --runtime-version "16.4.0"` to `OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS`. Works for me.
Original source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683214?answerId=752360022#752360022
Xcode version: Version 14.2 (14C18)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I was using custom framework, and when I embed it in my app. it showing me error
***The code signature version is no longer supported.***
i spend whole day to struggle with it. Finally resolved it by adding user-defined settings. In new Xcode 13 which supports arm 64
Project target->Build Settings-> + sign to add user define setting and add a setting. then add **VALID_ARCHS** as a field under this add the value $(ARCHS_STANDARD). Automatically it will convert it arm64 arm 7.
see the attached[image] image for more reference.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I was using custom static framework target, and I embed it in my app, Finally resolved it by don't embed it or change static to dynamic framework target

Answer (score -1):

When nothing else works, try turning your device off and back on again. Strangely this finally fixed it for me.