# added firebase libraries and now unable to install app on older iphone from xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I recently added in a login screen to my app with FireBase. It will no longer let me install to my Iphone 7 + with iOS 15.5 and Xcode 13.4. It worked before adding the firebase libraries. It does still work in the similuatlre. It's only when I added the firebase is when It stopped loading on my iphone 7 +. I'm building an app to help me with day-to-day work and to share with others for classifying and counting seeds in pictures. I also like to update statistics for predicting brackets for sports for fun. I've tried the following:

- Restarting everything
- Updating libraries
- Resolve libraries
- reset libraries
- Added the --generate-entitlement-der under other code signing flags

  - I did this for the pods and for the app
- updated my Certificate and made sure my coco pods were set to do not embed (actually tried everything)
- Tried changing the iOS versions to 15.5 for everything

Are there any other suggestions? I'm not sure what else to try or why its not letting me

```
Details

Unable to install "PlantAssist"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-06-09 21:46:53 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
The code signature version is no longer supported.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008029)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010ab909d1 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010abccce7 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102b9c7f6 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010abcca1d -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1422
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x00000001090a2668 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.301 + 3414
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102cce3f4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102ccf4dc __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 372
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81bd4a0cc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81bd4b317 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81bd51317 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81bd51dfd _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81bd5beee _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 753
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff81befefd0 _pthread_wqthread + 326
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff81befdf57 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_isWireless" = 1;
    "device_model" = "iPhone9,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.5 (19F77)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 555115;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402620375";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.6.1";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.5";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.5";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.4 (Build 21F79)
Xcode 13.4 (20503) (Build 13F17a)
Timestamp: 2022-06-09T16:46:53-05:00
```

Comment: try this --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/70369149/18202989

Comment: I tried that and i got the same error