# Stange update error when running a project

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, firebase

The title says it all. I'm getting a weird combination of errors when building this app. I didn't get these yesterday and all of a sudden I'm getting these. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467306/the-code-signature-version-is-no-longer-supported) help?

Comment: Can you please share the MacOS version and XCode Version?

Comment: That didn't help @MuhtasimUlfatTanmoy. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: And I just edited the post for the version numbers, @JAINESHDOSHI