# Xcode 13.4.1 generates an unsupported code signature version

Tags: xcode, code-signing, codesign, xcode13

I'm getting this error: `The code signature version is no longer supported` when trying to run an app. This has to do with an embedded framework which has an old code signature version.

`codesign -dv TheFramework.framework` yields `CodeDirectory v=20200`.

Consulting [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/using-the-latest-code-signature-format), it seems the code signature version needs to be at least 20400.

However, this code signature is generated **by Xcode 13.4.1 on macOS 12.5** using what looks like the correct command (specifically the `--generate-entitlement-der` mentioned in the article):

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign [big long identity string] --generate-entitlement-der --timestamp\=none --preserve-metadata\=identifier,entitlements,flags --generate-entitlement-der [full path to TheFramework.framework]
```

Update:

I just noticed that `codesign -dv` reports that the executable is the plist file instead of the binary. That's clearly wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467306/the-code-signature-version-is-no-longer-supported) answer your question?