# Unable to install "MyApp" in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, installation, build

I am facing this issue when I try to run the app in Xcode. This issue happens once in a while, but can be fixed with the second run or restarting the computer. However, I tried to restart the computer and checked for the latest updates for both my computer and my phone and still the same issue occurs.

```
    Details

Unable to install "Ingine"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-08-31 10:31:47 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
The code signature version is no longer supported.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008029)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010fe589d1 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010fe94ce7 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001097ef7d6 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010fe94a1d -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1422
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000112ac9668 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.301 + 3414
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001099213d4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001099224bc __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 372
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81a5260cc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81a527317 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81a52d317 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81a52ddfd _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81a537eee _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 753
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff81a6dafd0 _pthread_wqthread + 326
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff81a6d9f57 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone10,6";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.6.1 (19G82)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 12161;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402620375";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.6.1";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.5";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.5";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.5.1 (Build 21G83)
Xcode 13.4.1 (20504) (Build 13F100)
Timestamp: 2022-08-31T14:31:47+04:00
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467306/the-code-signature-version-is-no-longer-supported

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The code signature version is no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467306/the-code-signature-version-is-no-longer-supported)