# Why can I run my iOS app on the Device but can on Simulator after installing Firebase?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I'm using the latest version of XCode(14.3.1) and the latest version of iOS (16.5) on my device. On my iPhone simulator I have iOS (16.4). After installing FirebaseFirestore to my project, I'm no longer available to instal an app on my device only on the simulator. Build is succesfull in both cases but when I want to run on my device I see a modal windown "Unable to instal "AppName".

In short th details are saying "The code signature version is no longer supported." Detaild issues description is below

```
Details

Unable to install "North London Anthems"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-06-07 23:10:28 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
The code signature version is no longer supported.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487925;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008029)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010f220b1c DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 300
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010f255000 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 136
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001062c7480 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 76
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010f254d7c -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1208
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000010fabbc00 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.147 + 2340
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001063d1de0 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001063d284c __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 152
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018364a874 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018364c400 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000183653a88 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001836545f8 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018365f244 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001837f8074 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001837f6d94 start_wqthread + 8
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone15,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.5 (20F66)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 3957;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402620375";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos16.4";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.4";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.4 (Build 22F66)
Xcode 14.3.1 (21815) (Build 14E300c)
Timestamp: 2023-06-07T19:10:28-04:00
```

Latest Cocoapod and ruby

Comment: I haven't seen this before but it might be worth checking out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467306/the-code-signature-version-is-no-longer-supported) post, if you haven't come across it already. There are some comments on various answers from people with success on Xcode 14.