# The code signature version is no longer supported - facebook-ios-sdk

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, code-signing, facebook-ios-sdk

The issue started to appear after I have implemented facebook-ios-sdk in order to use facebook signing in in my app. While testing on a simulator, everything works perfectly, but as long as I try to install the app to my IPhone 11, I get this error:

[Unable to install "App"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSaRs.png)

In the "Details" I get such information:

```
Details

Unable to install "App"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-07-04 09:50:39 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
The code signature version is no longer supported.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487925;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008029)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001105ecb1c DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 300
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110621000 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 136
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106493480 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 76
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110620d7c -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1208
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000010fa47c00 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.147 + 2340
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010659dde0 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010659e84c __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 152
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018e11e874 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018e120400 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018e127a88 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018e1285f8 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018e133244 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018e2cc074 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018e2cad94 start_wqthread + 8
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone12,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.5.1 (20F75)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 17540;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402620375";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos16.4";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.4";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.4.1 (Build 22F82)
Xcode 14.3.1 (21815) (Build 14E300c)
Timestamp: 2023-07-04T11:50:39+02:00
```

XCode version: 14.3.1
macOS Version: 13.4.1
IOS version: 16.5.1
facebook-ios-sdk version: 16.1.2

Seeking for help!

I have already tried a lot of things, among them:

- [--generate-entitlement-der flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68467307/21804034)
- ["Do not embed"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69588949/21804034)
- Renewed Provisioning Profile and IOS Distribution Certificates
- Cleaned Build Folder
- Restarted mac
- Restarted IPhone
- [pod deintegrate / install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73209042/21804034)
- Tried different versions of facebook-ios-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the thing that fixed the issue was suggested by chat gpt:

> Corrupted Derived Data: Clearing derived data often solves a lot of
> mysterious Xcode issues. Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations ->
> Derived Data, then click on the arrow to open the folder in Finder,
> close Xcode, and delete the Derived Data folder.

I have just removed "Derived Data" folder, then deleted FacebookLogin from "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content" and it helped.

[image: Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndege.png)

I hope this helped someone of you!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I have posted the question on github of facebook-ios-sdk-next [here](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/issues/447#issue-1858845554).

And I solved it by doing these steps [source answer here](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/issues/423#issuecomment-1562937617):

1. appname => build phases => Link binary with libraries
2. removed all facebook packages

[image]

Thanks and hope that will help you.